# I am unable to download the Sagemaker file "Response entity too large"

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, stable-diffusion

I'm using SageMaker Studio Lab and trying to download a file that's 2GB large. Unfortunately, I get the error `Response entity too large`.

I don't know how to make the server allow the download of a large file. A friend said that I could split the file, however, the file is a stable diffusion model and it cannot be split.

I don't know if in the settings there is an option to increase the size of files for download.

Answer (score 1):

based on the link provided it seems you're using SageMaker Studio Lab. Unfortunately, this is a free service provided by AWS with limited customisation options.

The easiest option would be to upload your file to Amazon S3, then download it from there.

#### Steps

1. Sign up for an Amazon Web Services (AWS) account.
2. Create a "bucket" in Amazon S3.
3. Generate AWS security credentials -- you'll need to generate [access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#Using_CreateAccessKey).
4. Open the terminal in SageMaker Studio Lab and run `aws configure`, then enter your access keys from before.
5. Finally, run the command `aws s3 cp my_local_file s3://my_bucket/my_file_name`

Good luck! :)